# how to change textview font family of whole app from one place android?

Tags: android

can i change font family of all textviews of in layouts ?

I have searched many sites on google but don't find any solution for this

either i have to customize textview or set font family to individual textview

Comment: https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: You have to set font to individual textview

Comment: Create your custom Class extended by TextView, implement font change in this class. Use this class in xml and code instead TextView. If you want to change font for all your classes instances - just change font in your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

use this sdk:

```
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
```

in your app class extends Application :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/xxx.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());
}
```

and in each activity add this:

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));

    }
```

remind add your font in assetsfolde/fonts

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">name_of_your_font</item>
```

in your styles.xml AppTheme as attribute.

Comment: THANK YOU for responding, but when i add any style item with font family it gives error to ''BUTTON"  error is :---- "android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class Button"